# How to parse a JSON_ARRAYAGG result from kafka-connect to a JSON subobject in my kafka message

Tags: oracle, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have a kafka-connector that is connected to an oracle database.

I use a request that get this kind of result by using JSON_ARRAYAGG function from oracle:

| id | codeNumber | components |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12345 | [{"id": 1, "value": 1},{"id": 2, "value": 2}]} |
| 2 | 64890 | [{"id": 3, "value": 3},{"id": 4, "value": 4}]} |

I use Avro schema and the resulting schema is the following:

```
{
  "type": "record",
  "name": "MyObject",
  "namespace": "com.example.model",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "id",
      "type": "long"
    },
    {
      "name": "codeNumber",
      "type": "int"
    },
    {
      "name": "components",
      "type": [
        "null",
        "string"
      ],
      "default": null
    }
  ],
  "connect.version": 1,
  "connect.name": "com.example.model.MyObject"
}
```

I would like to know if there is a possibility to parse my "components" field into a Json format instead of getting a String.. Can I use some Transformation or Conversion to do it ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

I tried some options like:

- ExtractField
- ReplaceField

but I think I don't understand very well there purpose

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you will need to write [your own Transform class](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/connect/transforms/custom.html).

Otherwise, ksqlDB has its own JSON extraction functions that can build a new topic from that string data.

Comment: Thanks @OneCricketeer, Sorry if I'm a newbie on this topic, but Ksql console is always available or administrator of our kafka can blocked me ? because, currently I don't know how and where to try to execute ksql query to resolve my issue.

Comment: Ksql is a standalone product. You need to run. Doesn't require admin permissions